# Internet Explorer 9 Crashes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer-9, coded-ui-tests

I open Internet Explorer 9: i type browse to Google the page load and as it finishes loading the (Tab) Hangs i cant click any links or do any thing, however i can open new tab and type in another site while the other tab is hanging but once i type any site in the new tab it hangs too and so on!

the internet explorer 9 64bit works fine.!

here is what i tried to do:

1. Turned off Internet Explorer 9 Feature from "Turn on/Off Features"
   in control panel, then turned it on, didn't fix the problem.
2. downgraded to internet explorer 8, and same issue happened in IE8
   too !!!. so i upgraded back to IE9 (issue remains).
3. Switched to Software rendering, (didn't fix problem).
4. Updated my graphics card to latest driver.
5. Opened IE9 with no Adds on.
6. Disabled all adds-on

all this didn't fix the problem!

i need to make it work because i need to do UI Test Automation by Visual studio 2010, and i cant get it to work for Fire-Fox v13 i guess its not supported.

any one faced this problem before and know how to fix it ?

im using Windows 7 64bit

Comment: Does IE work if you open it manually? If it doesn't you will get a better response to your question on Super User or one of Microsoft forums.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to and can install VS2010 Feature Pack 2, I believe it supports running coded ui tests in Firefox.  There is information on that [At MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269468.aspx), however, that page recommends Firefox 3.5 or 3.6.